# JavaScript text fade jags in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opacity, fade

The text in this example moves slightly right before fading out and corrects left after fading back in. I am only seeing this effect on XP(SP3) with Chrome (version 26.0.1410.64 m).  The same version of Chrome on Windows7 does not exhibit this behaviour.

The only solution I can find is to reset the bold font to normal before starting the fade but this would not look so good either.

This is part of some larger code and I am looking for a JavaScript solution rather than css.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Fade moves text horizontally in Chrome with Windows XP</title>

<style type="text/css">
body         {font-family: Arial; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function setOpacity(id,level) {
var a = document.getElementById(id);
if(a) {
a.style.opacity = level;
}
}

var duration = 1000; 
var steps = 22;

function fadeIn(id){
for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += (1 / steps)) {
setTimeout("setOpacity('" + id + "'," + i + ")", i * duration);
}
}

function fadeOut(id) {
for (i = 0; i <= 1; i += (1 / steps)) {
setTimeout("setOpacity('" + id + "'," + (1 - i) + ")", i * duration);
}
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="fade">
This text moves slightly to the right before fading out and resets itself back to the  left after fading back in.
<br />
This text moves slightly to the right before fading out and resets itself back to the left after fading back in.
</div>

<p onclick="fadeOut('fade')">Click to fade out</p>
<p onclick="fadeIn('fade')">Click to fade in</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i could not check right now my self, but does the whole look of the text change (looking slightly bolder)? or is just the text itself moving (having more space on the left)?

Comment: hi t.niese - more so that the whole of the text is shifting horizontally, about 1px or 2px.

Comment: I am also witnessing similar behaviour in the Opera Mobile Emulator